# Can I be in character as the Silver Shroud and still complete the optional objective?

Tags: fallout-4

I am on the quest "The Silver Shroud".

There is an optional objective

> Save Kent

If I progress in character as The Silver Shroud, make all of the choices as the Silver Shroud would, I am unable to complete the optional objective.

Is it possible to complete the optional objective as the Silver Shroud (in character)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that I faced in this quest was:

> Sinjin had a gun to Kent's head and my approach to the scene was from the front. I tried everything I could think of to take down Sinjin with quick strikes with melee weapon, a really powerful sniper rifle but nothing was working. My dialog had already caused Sinjin's henchmen to flee. So all I had to do was take down one guy.

So I needed time to get more shots with a very high damage. And for me Jet did the trick. The 10 second slowdown of time helped there. Secondly I needed to boost my damage, because none of my rifles or pistols were working. Psycho provides a 25% boost to damage.

So with that in mind this is how I finally completed the optional objective.

1. Have a really good high damage, low firing rate like pistol or rifle.
2. Have some Jet, Psycho or any time slowing/damage modifying chem.
3. After the third intimidation prompt as the Silver Shroud jump into your inventory and pop the Jet + Psycho. I popped one Jet and 3 Psychos. Got really close and went into VATS and lined up shots to the head.

Make sure you get close to the platform, so that you get a high VATS rate for the head. VATS modifying/AP boosting/critical hit gear is a bonus for this.

Comment: -1 Please don't do that. Just use a spoiler tag if you must. This answer is less helpful when intentionally obfuscated.

Comment: Guess in my haste to get back to the game, I half-assed the answer. Sorry. Hope the clarification helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Syringer Rifle you find somewhere in the hospital and use the Stun Ammo on him.
Just Hipfire after your third Silver Shroud Intimidation. He'll lie on the floor and is fair game.

Answer (score -1):

You can also just use the other speech option and tell Sinjin to kill you in front of Kent. Then proceed to kill all of them instead.

Comment: OP wants to know if he can save Kent while staying _in character_.