# Kent Connolly is no where to be found even after the quest

Tags: fallout-4

I saved a Kent Connolly from certain death as part of the Silver Shroud quest.

Afterwards, he was no where to be found - what gives? After all [those pains](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243284/can-i-be-in-character-as-the-silver-shroud-and-still-complete-the-optional-objec) I am unable to find the certain comic loving ghoul what gives? He is supposed to give me an armor upgrade to my shroud armor.

Where is he?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the character Kent Connolly gets stuck in the hospital for some reason.

Solving this requires access to the console. You can bring his object reference to yourself:

- Go to Goodneighbor.
- Type `prid 000228ac` - this is his reference ID and not base ID.
- Do a `moveto player`.

Now he will move into his room in The Memory Den. You can either talk to him or turn on the Silver Shroud Radio and he will mention armor upgrades waiting for you, since you are the best Shroud. These are level specific.

The Silver Shroud Radio will also seem to inoperative at this point (not a bug since at the end of saving Kent, he specifically mentions not doing the radio ever again). But at each of the upgrade levels for the Silver Shroud Armor (25?/35/45), Kent will go on the air in Goodneighbor and call for the Silver Shroud at which point you can talk to him in the Memory Den for the Armor upgrade.

And never cross my path, I am the Shroud!!!! (phew)

Answer (score 1):

Kent should be with Hancock in the Old State House in Goodneighbor after you save him.

He'll be there when you turn in the quest to Hancock, then he'll go to his room in the Memory Den.

If he's not there, then you've probably run into a bug. If you're on PC, you can deal with this situation using console commands, as explained in [ヴァイシャリ's answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/247299/108003)

Comment: In my game Hancock was already in Sanctuary, and I could not find him.But backtracking back to the hospital where Sinjin was about to kill him, there I found him. That is how I found out his PrId.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ Ah, that would make sense that things might get a little goofy if you already have Hancock as a companion. Sometimes companions go back to their original areas after a quest involving them. Did you happen to check the Old State House?

Comment: I did. He was not there. He was still stuck in the hospital where Sinjin had a gun pointed to him. And the latest patch did not fix it. I had no idea the suit could be upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

For gamers of console:

I found that if you corral him into the elevator and take it down with him in it, he'll start walking out on his own once he's in the room with the exit.

NPC's and companions were made so they would walk to move out of your way if you make it clear that you want them to move. So by corral I mean keep running into Kent until he gets out of your way into the elevator.

It's somewhat time-consuming but if you don't want to maze through the hospital next time you want to get him to improve your silver shroud costume then it's your only option at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I had Hancock as a follower while doing this quest. I was able to talk to Hancock and Kent straight after I killed the boss and saved Kent. I think this is what caused him to remain in Milton General Hospital for me.
 So heads up, don't have Hancock as a follower while doing this.

Comment: Hmm. I too did have Hancock as a follower when I faced this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am a console player.  When he started the radio station back up to upgrade the suit,  I couldn't find him in goodneighbor.  I went back to the hospital and after killing raiders, I found him in the same spot I left him.  He still upgraded my suit from there though.

Answer (score 1):

I had Hancock as my companion as well, and this time, Kent got stuck at Milton General Hospital as well. On my 2 previous run-throughs I had different companions and he ended up back in Goodneighbor.
Either way, you can get your upgrades after 3 days to 1 week passes (in game). If you *don't* get the full 87/87 defense upgrade, make sure to check back at level 35 & 45. If you're level 45+, you'll automatically get the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Saving Kent is optional, and in my case he died.
Make sure you are dressed as the Silver Shroud when you are at the hospital, and to kill everyone after killing Sinjin. The game will tell you to meet Hancock at Goodneighbor - have him join you, then talk to him: this will finish the mission and you can now get rid of the uniform and put it in your inventory.